# Images appearing in all but 1 flask page

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am creating a web app in flask, python, mysql. When viewing every other page on my website my images load, but when viewing one specific page, I can't get any images to load using already working code. Is there any reason this may be?

Code for one of my working pages:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<!-- home style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/home.css">

    {% for index in range(0, shoes|count, 3) %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="shop/item/{{ shoes[index][0] }}">
                <h4>{{ shoes[index][1] }}</h4>
                <img src="{{ shoes[index][7] }}" alt="" width="250px" height="150px">
            </a>
        </div>
        {% if shoes|count - index >= 2 %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="shop/item/{{ shoes[index][0] + 1 }}">
                <h4>{{ shoes[index + 1][1] }}</h4>
                <img src="{{ shoes[index + 1][7] }}"  alt="" width="250px" height="150px">
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endif%}
        {% if shoes|count - index >= 3 %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="shop/item/{{ shoes[index][0] + 2 }}">
                <h4>{{ shoes[index + 2][1] }}</h4>
                <img src="{{ shoes[index + 2][7] }}"  alt="" width="250px" height="150px">
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endif%}
    </div>

    {% endfor %} 

{% endblock %}
```

and its python file:

```
from app import app, mysql
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/shop')
def shop():
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM shoes")

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('shop.html', shoes = data)
```

Now the failing page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<!-- home style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/home.css">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="{{ item[0][7] }}" alt="" width="250px" height="150px">
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

and its python file:

```
from app import app, mysql
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/shop/item/<id>')
def item(id):

    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE id=id")

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('item.html', item = data)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT;

I know the sql data is being sent to this page correctly because when I inspect element on the empty image, I have the exact same src url as on the working page. Also, all other attributes of the row i fetched are correct.
My sql table looks like this:

```
id | name                             | size | price  | primarycolor | secondarycolor | othercolor | img                     |
+----+----------------------------------+------+--------+--------------+----------------+------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2013 Air Jordan 11 Retro         | 10.0 | 215.00 | black        | gamma blue     | NULL       | static/pics/gamma.png
```

Comment: Can u include an example of your sql table row or `print` what `data` have?

Comment: And in this expression: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE id=id")` is `id` of your `item` view function really getting passed to your sql expression?

Comment: I think your `sql` expression should be: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE id=%d" % id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs are made up of directories and filenames. Anything that precedes a `/` is considered a directory. Anything after the final `/` is the filename. Your problem is that you're using relative URLs. When you say

```
static/pics/gamma.png
```

your browser makes a request for that file relative to the current page's directory. In the case of URLs like `/` and `/shop`, the directory is `/`. The browser will request `/static/pics/gamma.png`.

In the case of URLs like `/shop/item/1`, the directory is `/shop/item/`. Your browser will then request `/shop/item/static/pics/gamma.png`.

Since your URLs match the former, you should store them as absolute URLs (with the leading `/`) so that the browser will make the correct request.

On a semi-related note, you should be using `url_for` whenever possible.

```
url_for('static', filename='css/home.css')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `item` view function, you are not passing the value of `id` into your `sql` expression, here is the safe way to do it:

```
@app.route('/shop/item/<id>')
def item(id):

    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    sql_exp = "SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE id=%d"
    cursor.execute(sql_exp, id)

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('item.html', item = data)
```