# Flask web app do not show image properly

Tags: python, html, flask

I don't know why my Flask app show image in index link but do not show in other link. It is work properly in `/index`, shows every image. But when open `/stream` or `/posts/id` link app do not show the image, show only the text.

**Python code**

```
@app.route('/new_post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def post():
    form = forms.PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        filename = secure_filename(form.photo.data.filename)
        filePath=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

        form.photo.data.save(filePath)

        models.Post.create(user=g.user._get_current_object(),
                       content=form.content.data.strip(),
                       path = ("/uploads/"+ filename))

        flash("Message posted: Thanks!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('post.html', form=form)

@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    stream = models.Post.select().limit(100)
    return render_template('stream.html', stream=stream)

@app.route('/stream')
@app.route('/stream/<username>')
def stream(username=None):
    template = 'stream.html'
    if username and username != current_user.username:
        try:
            user=models.User.select().where(models.User.username**username).get()
        except models.DoesNotExist:
            abort(404)
        else:
            stream = user.posts.limit(100)
    else:
        stream = current_user.get_stream().limit(100)
        user = current_user
    if username:
        template = 'user_stream.html'
    return render_template(template, stream=stream, user=user)

@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def view_post(post_id):
    posts=models.Post.select().where(models.Post.id == post_id)
    if posts.count()==0:
        abort(404)
    return render_template('stream.html', stream=posts)
```

**HTML code**

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in stream %}
  <article>
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ url_for('stream', username=post.user.username) }}">
        {{ post.user.username }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <i class="clock"></i>
    <time data-time="{{ post.timestamp }}" >
      {{ post.timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}
    </time>
    <a href="{{ url_for('view_post', post_id=post.id) }}" class="view">View</a>
    <div class="post">
      {{ post.content }}
    </div>
    <div class="image" >
        <a href="{{ url_for('view_post', post_id=post.id) }}" target="_blank"</a>
       <img src="{{ post.path }}" alt="" style="width:720px;height:720px;">
    </div>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I did almost the same things as in other project, but have never faced this type of problem. May be I have done something wrong, but I can't find that.

**Post Model**

```
class Post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model=User, 
        related_name='posts'
    )
    content = CharField(max_length=120)
    path = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-timestamp',)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images appearing in all but 1 flask page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279228/images-appearing-in-all-but-1-flask-page)

Comment: Is the last anchor tag on its own?

Comment: Can you add your post model to the question?

Comment: @dirn I don't think this is duplicate, That question and answers didn't help me.

Comment: @roy Yes, the last anchor tag on its own.

Comment: @splinks Post edited

Comment: Does `post.path` start with a `/`? If not, you have the same relative URL problem.

Comment: I forgot to thanks you @dirn